# Java best practice when to use Lambda exprection

Tags: java

I have a case where service which returns optional and that value is used only for the condition only and if true return success else throws an exception, so for this do I need to use a lambda expression.

```
Optional<MyClass> val = service.getMyclass();
if(val.isPresent) {
 //some operation
}else{
   //throw exception
}
```

Comment: Paresh kindly read through Java documentation. The question you are asking is very very generic and highly opinion based.

Comment: FYI, `class` is a keyword in java, should pick another example for demo purpose.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try below given code.

```
Optional<MyClass> var = service.getMyclass();
MyClass val = var.orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);
```

Comment: in case if there is a code block in the in the if cocndition then.

Comment: nested optional
```Optional<Optional<MyClass>> val = service.getMyclass();```
```MyClass i = val.flatMap(Function.identity()).orElseThrow(RuntimeException::new);```